# Sorting users by score - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, each user has a karma/score that i'm calculating through the user model as follows:

```
after_invitation_accepted :increment_score_of_inviter

def increment_score_of_inviter
  invitation_by.increment!(:score, 10)
end

def comment_vote_count
  Vote.find(comment_ids).count * 2
end

def calculated_vote_count
  base_score + comment_vote_count
end

def recalculate_score!
  update_attribute(:score, calculated_vote_count)
end
```

I'm trying to create paginated list of all the users, sorted by their scores. With thousands of users, how do I do this efficiently?

I was think of using:

```
User.all.sort_by(&:calculated_vote_count)
```

But, this would be pretty heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...using `User.all` upon a table full of records will be a memory hog for your application. Instead you should try to accomplish what you want on the DB layer.

At this point I'm assuming `base_score` is one of the table columns (is `base_score` same as `score`?), so you'd have to do something like the following (using LEFT JOIN):

```
User.select("users.*, (COUNT(votes.id) * 2 + users.base_score) AS calculated_vote_count").joins("LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.user_id = user.id").order("calculated_vote_count DESC")
```

And then you can paginate the results the way you like.

I didn't test it, but it should work. Let me know if doesn't.

Comment: But there is a `vote` column already right? You don't want to be doing calculation when ordering users. You should have the score cached somewhere, that's for sure.

Comment: Robin, check the method `comment_vote_count` in the his code example. He doesn't have a `vote` column, unfortunately. The votes are computed in a different table. That's why I proposed the using JOIN. Ideally, he could be caching and/or he could be even using triggers to increment a `votes` column in `users` table.

Comment: But he doesn't want to order by vote_count, he wants to order by score, or am I missing something? However he updates the score columns is another story, but there is a `score` column, and that's what he should use to order his users.

Comment: As he mentioned on the example above, he's trying to sort by `calculated_vote_count` method, which references the `comment_vote_count` method, which counts the amount of votes in `votes` table through `Vote` model for the given user. All of that logic is what I've tried to translate into SQL in my solution above, as you can see. Don't blame me, blame the question owner's logic. ;)

Comment: I'm not blaming anyone ;) I'm trying to help him. He said `I'm trying to create paginated list of all the users, sorted by their scores`. His code is probably wrong, and not what he's actually trying to do, I'm guessing.

Comment: Heh, sorry. I was just picking on you. But you're right. It looks confusing, nonetheless. But we already gave him a better path to follow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50906/discussion-between-leandroico-and-robin)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward:

```
User.order('score DESC').all
```

Obviously you'd have pagination, `User.order('score DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)` with Kaminari.